# Open pdf file from R

Tags: r, pdf

I'm trying to open a pdf file from R. For this I'm using the `openPDF()`  function from the Biobase package. It works well if the path to file does not contain spaces between words (e.g. `"/Users/Admin/Desktop/test.pdf"`) but it does not work if the path contains spaces (e.g. `/Users/Admin/Desktop/**My Project**/test.pdf`). How can I make it accept any path or how should I automatically transform a given path such that is recognised by `openPDF()`? I would also like it to work on both mac and windows. Here is the code:

```
library(Biobase)
pdf("test.pdf")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
openPDF(paste(getwd(), "/test.pdf", sep=""))
```

Answer (score 6):

No need for external packages. This will work with the base R function `system()`

For a Mac / Unix:

```
path = '/path/to/file.pdf'
system(paste0('open "', path, '"'))
```

For a PC:

```
path = '\path\to\file.pdf'
system(paste0('start "', path, '"'))
```

Or if you want the path fixed, you can just incorporate it right into the `paste0` string and do it in one line:

```
system('open "/path/to/file.pdf"')
```

Comment: `system(paste0('open "', path, '"'))` works for Windows.

Answer (score 4):

It's a bug in `openPDF`.  You can work around it by calling `normalizePath`.

```
openPDF(normalizePath("test.pdf"))
```

For the record, `openPDF` is just a wrapper to `shell.exec` under Windows so you can just call that instead.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work
`openPDF(normalizePath(c(getwd(), "test.pdf")))`

Comment: Try: `openPDF(normalizePath(file.path(getwd(), "test.pdf")))` or just `openPDF(normalizePath("test.pdf"))` as was suggested.

Comment: I've no Mac to test this, so you'll have to try a few things for me.  Does `shortPathName` exist on the Mac?  If so, try `openPDF(shortPathName("test.pdf"))`.  Also try `openPDF(shQuote("test.pdf"))`.

Answer (score 4):

An easy alternative is

```r
browseURL(paste0(getwd(),"/","file.pdf"))
```

This function is available in R base.

Answer (score 3):

fs package provide a cross plataform solution:

```r
library(fs)
file_show(path(getwd(), "file.pdf"))
```